# Conversion from string "31/03/2012" to type 'Date' is not valid

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis, datetime, globalization

My web app is running perfectly in asp vb.net editor. But when i run my web app through IIS7 then i get this error. What am i missing in configuring IIS7? Is there anyone who can suggest something?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Where do you get the error? What's the stack trace?

Comment: Have you tried `Convert.ToDateTime("31/03/2012")`?

Comment: Using DateTime.Parse on 31/03/2012 will result in the following error "System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.". Flipping the 03 and 31 around works though.

Comment: show code where you are getting error and what you have tried

Comment: DateTime conversions are locale dependent as far as I know ... try parsing it with with a specific format

Answer (score 7):

Because your IIS7 is configured for the English Language and that date is probably Italian or something similar. You'll have to tell to the `Date.Parse` which culture to use.

Something like

```
dateValue = Date.Parse(yourDate, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("it-IT"))
```

Or you can change the culture in your IIS7

Here there are the [instructions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771836%28WS.10%29.aspx)

for example if you use the UI

> Using the UI Open IIS Manager and navigate to the level you want to
>   manage. *(omissis)*
>
> In Features View, double-click .NET Globalization.
>
> On the .NET Globalization page, in the property sheet, click to select
>   the global setting you want to edit, and select a value from the
>   drop-down list.
>
> In the Actions pane, click Apply.

Or you could set the culture of your app in the `web.config`

```
<system.web>
    <globalization culture="it-IT" uiCulture="it-IT"/>
</system.web>
```

Comment: The regional settings is probably set to that of the United State ("en-us"). Date formats vary by region, not so much by language.

Comment: Thanks xanatos, that IIS7 adjustment fixed that issue in my code.

Comment: I can't give this answer enough upvotes.  I spent all morning twiddling my machine locale settings trying to work out why this code was suddenly choking on date formats.  Turns out even though I didn't change the code, I moved to IIS hosting.  This not only solved my problem, but gives me a variety of ways to fix it.

Answer (score 4):

If you are sure that the date is always in exactly that format, then you can use ParseExact instead:

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(
               "31/03/2012",
               "dd/MM/yyyy",
               System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the CDate function to parse the date.

```
Dim dDate As Date = CDate("31/03/2012")
```

The advantage of using this function over the DateTime parsing functions is that you can feed it any acceptable format of date string and it will convert it.  It will throw an error if it can't parse the date.

Comment: But the disadvantage is that you may get unpredictable results on an ambiguous date such as `"03/05/2011"`