# Conversion from string "31/03/2012" to type 'Date' is not valid

Tags: asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Conversion from string “31/03/2012” to type 'Date' is not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7945310/conversion-from-string-31-03-2012-to-type-date-is-not-valid)

I tried Data.Parse and Convert.todatetime but now it says that
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime. I also configured .NetGlobalozation and setUI Culture to "English (United States) (en-US)" with the default "Invariant Language (Invariant Country)" but no use. What am i missing ?? The stack trace is as follows..

> [FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.]
>   System.DateTimeParse.Parse(String s, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi,
>   DateTimeStyles styles) +2845862    System.DateTime.Parse(String s) +25
>   ProwessWebApp.Finyr.SSCreate_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   E:\DevVB2008\ProwessWebApp\ProwessWebApp\ProwessWebApp\Finyr.aspx.vb:130
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +111
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +110
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +10
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
>   +175    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +1565

Can u plz tell me what to do ??
Dev..

Comment: That's not a `en-US` date format, since we 'mericans typically use MM/dd/yyyy, not dd/MM/yyyy. Try `en-GB`.

Comment: Edit the original question instead of asking a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`31/03/2012` is not a valid english-us date. english-us uses a "month/day/year" ordering, while your input date is "day/month/year".

`03/31/2012` is the right ordering for your input, or use a different locale (french...).

Comment: en-GB done it right. Thanks a lot it solved my problem..

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the date is always in exactly that format, then you can use ParseExact instead:

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(
               "31/03/2012",
               "dd/MM/yyyy",
               System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```